# Rollback in Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a trigger `check_id`.
With that trigger I want to rollback an `Insert` Statement on `User` in case the `User.Id = 4`

```
ALTER TRIGGER check_id on USER
FOR INSERT
AS
 BEGIN

   IF 4 = (SELECT Id from inserted)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END
 END
```

However when I do a Insert on `User` with `Id = 4` like this:

```
INSERT INTO USER (Id, Name)
VALUES (4, 'Emmanuel')
```

I get an error:

> Rollback not available in an atomic process

What do I wrong? How can I rollback a INSERT within a trigger?

Comment: Is that all code? Cannot reproduce see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49123/1/0), when uncomment you get `"The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted."` Also naming table as keyword is very bad practice

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT Id from inserted` - it's non-deterministic, you get *one arbtitrary* row and all 24 others are **ignored**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Second as marc_s suggest it won't work with multiple rows see `INSERT INTO [user](Id, Name) VALUES (4, 'Emmanuel'), (5, 'AAA');`

Comment: @marc_s thanks for your help!  How could I only rollback the first insert?

Comment: @lad2025 or how could I rollback all inserts ? Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnSmith Can't you just add check constraint like `ALTER TABLE [user]
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_user CHECK (id <> 4)` instead of trigger? [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90523/1/0)

Comment: You cannot rollback just a single insert - either you abort the *whole transaction* - or you let it go forward. There's no "cherry picking" here - it's an all-or-nothing situation

Comment: @marc_s and how can I abort the whole transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use check constraint instead:

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90523/1/0)**

```
 ALTER TABLE [user] ADD CONSTRAINT chk_user CHECK (id <> 4);
```